# Can I do a section with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having one section of a site which I wondered how can I replicate it using bootstrap, I tried couple of ways but I couldn't get the same result. 
I cannot figure out which one will be a row and which one will be a column.

Here is a picture of the section:

[image]

Thank you in advance!
I am using bootstrap 3.4.1 if that matters.

Comment: You can achieve this using bootstrap grid. look here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward, you just need to do some nesting of the rows for the bottom. [Here is a working solution](https://codepen.io/schrdr/pen/bPqXXJ?editors=110).

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
  min-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 block">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 block">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 block">
          content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 block">
          content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 block">
          content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 block">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response! I will try it tomorrow and one more thing, sorry for the stupid question, I am still learning. Thanks again!

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)